# Word up, and where it came from

Tags: slang

I'm aware of English's unpredictable nature in wording, but this phrase got me thinking.

What is the origination of the phrase `word up`... a lot of times shortened to just `word!`

I understand the meaning of the phrase to be:

- Great!
- Alright!
- Ok!
- I agree!
- That's awesome!

, but how did `word` end up being a synonym for these?

Comment: In the beginning was the Word ... everything else is derivative :)